# JFileChooser selecting a file

Tags: java

My code is working fine to save a file with FileChoser. But how can I make it accurate and perfect when a user doesn't select an absolute path for a file and closes it abruptly?

```
public class HTMLtoPDF {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void convertHtmlToPdf() {
        try {

            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            // Set extension filter
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF File (*.pdf)", "*.pdf");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
            // Show save file dialog
            //The stage for show dialouge is get from MainClass stage
            File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(MainClass.getStage());


            Client client = new Client("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);


            String currentUrl = TabController.getWebEngine().getLocation().toString();
            client.convertURI(currentUrl, fileStream);

            fileStream.close();

            //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```